# How to create schema with thick client in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

Apache Ignite doesn't support creating schema with DDL yet. So is there any way I can create a new schema in runtime? I tried to add a template cache configuration in a thick client, but schema config doesn't work.

```
CacheConfigration cfg = new CacheConfigration();
cfg.setName("MyTemplte*");
cfg.setSqlSchema("NEW_SCHEMA");
ignite.addCacheConfigration(cfg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ignite.createCache(cfg)` or `ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg)` to create a new cache with the specified schema.

`addCacheConfiguration` only creates a template, but does not create any schemas or caches.

See https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/schemas for more details.

Comment: Thank you Pavel! It works.

Comment: @Pavel - is it possible to see the new schema in Gridgain control center under SQL?